# How to escape HTML special characters in Solidity?

Tags: string, escaping, user-input, solidity

I am trying the approach below. It is based on [some of Uniswap's code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/NFTDescriptor.sol#L85).

I am curious as to whether it will work at reasonable cost or whether there is a better way.

```
function escapeHTML(string memory input)
    public
    pure
    returns (string memory)
{
    bytes memory inputBytes = bytes(input);
    uint extraCharsNeeded = 0;
    
    for (uint i = 0; i < inputBytes.length; i++) {
        bytes1 currentByte = inputBytes[i];
        
        if (currentByte == "&") {
            extraCharsNeeded += 4;
        } else if (currentByte == "<") {
            extraCharsNeeded += 3;
        } else if (currentByte == ">") {
            extraCharsNeeded += 3;
        }
    }
    
    if (extraCharsNeeded > 0) {
        bytes memory escapedBytes = new bytes(
            inputBytes.length + extraCharsNeeded
        );
        
        uint256 index;
        
        for (uint i = 0; i < inputBytes.length; i++) {
            if (inputBytes[i] == "&") {
                escapedBytes[index++] = "&";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "a";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "m";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "p";
                escapedBytes[index++] = ";";
            } else if (inputBytes[i] == "<") {
                escapedBytes[index++] = "&";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "l";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "t";
                escapedBytes[index++] = ";";
            } else if (inputBytes[i] == ">") {
                escapedBytes[index++] = "&";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "g";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "t";
                escapedBytes[index++] = ";";
            } else {
                escapedBytes[index++] = inputBytes[i];
            }
        }
        return string(escapedBytes);
    }
    
    return input;
}
```